# Can I create a new iOS flutter project, to upgrade a current projet in production?

Tags: flutter

I have a project that no longer works (impossible to run). I just know that I can run a blank project but not my original project anymore. Is it possible to create a new project with the same bundle id as my buggy project, and send it to production to update the current application?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to

Comment: Thank you I will try